# Identifier 'length' is not defined. 'null' does not contain such a member ng

Tags: angular

What i am trying to do is create a simple TODO application , i am using `ng2-redux` for state management , i am trying to access the `todos` array length in the view 
although the application compiles successfully there is still an error showing in my code,

**Error:**
[image]

**Current Code:**

**todo-dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux, select } from 'ng2-redux';
import { IAppState } from 'src/store';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './todo-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-dashboard.component.css'],
})
export class TodoDashboardComponent {
  @select() todos;
  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {}
}
```

**todo-dashboard-component.html**

```
  <div>
   Total Items:
   <span class="text-success">{{ (todos|async)?.length}}</span>
  </div>
```

**store.ts**

```
export interface IAppState {
  todos: any[];
  lastUpdated: Date;
}

export const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
  todos: [],
  lastUpdated: null,
};

export const rootReducer = (state: IAppState, action): IAppState => {}
```

i have tried adding `"strictNullChecks": false` in `tsconfig.json` file but no luck so if anyone could help me disable the error  or get through it i would highly appreciate it :)